# Pass a PowerShell array to a .NET function

Tags: powershell

I want to get some 10 values of type `short` from a .NET function.

In C# it works like this:

```
Int16[] values = new Int16[10];
Control1.ReadValues(values);
```

The C# syntax is `ReadValues(short[] values)`.

I tried something like this:

```
$Control1.ReadValues([array][int16]$Result)
```

But there are only zeroes in the array.

Comment: What do you mean by "But only zeroes in the array."? What is the value of `$Result`?

Comment: I'm also wondering how does it work in C# without return value, ref or out?

Comment: The ReadValues function returns 10 non zero values but the $Result array contain only zeroes. I guess that I do it totally wrong or maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `ReadValues()` or tell us which type `Control1` is?

Comment: I believe that the C# function have a ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mention:

> I believe that the C# function have a ref

So, the method signature is really:

```
ReadValues(ref short[] values)
```

Luckily, PowerShell has a `[ref]` type accelerator for this sort of situation

```
# Start by creating an array of Int16, length 10
$Result = [int16[]]@( ,0 * 10 )

# Pass the variable reference with the [ref] keyword
$Control1.ReadValues([ref]$Result)
```

For more inforation, see the [`about_Ref`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847792.aspx) help file